# Type hints of flow not stripped by babel

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, babeljs, flowtype

I have a React.JS project which uses a custom 'theme' with UI components.
This theme also provides build scripts (webpack config, babel configs, etc.).

I want to start using Flow in this project.
I installed the needed npm packages and added `flow` to babel's presets, then I added `props = {mytestprop: string}` to one of my React` classes.

Webpack compiled my code successfully, but the type hints were not stripped! Of course, the browser was not able to execute this code - when I try to run it, it raises`ReferenceError: string is not defined`.

The current list of presets from `.babelrc` is: `["es2015", "react", "stage-2", "flow"]`. I'm sure that this is the actual list used by babel because if I delete any of the first 3 presets, compilation fails.

Do you have any ideas on what could lead to this behavior when stripping Flow types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not that type annotations are not being stripped. It's that `{ mytestprop: string }` is *not a valid type annotation* on the right-hand side of an assignment because it clashes with the syntax for defining an object.

Specifically, when Flow's parser sees the statement `{ mytestprop: string }` it will interpret this as an attempt to create an object with a field named `mytestprop` with its value set to the value of the variable `string`, so it will leave the statement alone as it is, and you'll get the error you've seen in the browser.

The correct way to type object declarations is to type the left-hand side of the declaration.

For instance,

```
let myProps: { myTestProp: string } = { myTestProp: "testProp" };
```

if you aren't declaring your props separately, you could declare a custom type:

```
type myPropType = { myTestProp: string }
// ...
const myComponent = (props: myPropType) => //render your component
```

Since the `type` statement is exclusive to Flow and not a valid JavaScript statement, it will be stripped correctly.

Comment: omg. Yes, that was it. I typed `props = {...type hints}`:  '=' instead of ':'. Thank you